# touchpad is not working in ubuntu of acer espire es 15 which kernel is used?

Tags: touchpad

In my laptop acer aspire es 15 ,touchpad is not working in ubuntu 18.04,it is asking for kernel,so which kernel is used?

Comment: `uname -r` gives you the kernel version.